# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to send values to this XPath but getting the above error. I'm just not able to interact with that element only.

sometimes for same element I'll get error like `element not intarectable`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='address'])[1]")).sendKeys("banglore");
```

I also tried -

```
String Shipper_citynstate= "Aberdeen, SD, United States";
WebElement csShipper = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='address'])[1]"));
actions.sendKeys(csShipper,Shipper_citynstate).perform();
```

when I try this the script will run successfully but its not taking value.

I also tried `JavascriptExecutor` it is also not working.

Comment: Can you share the URL if it can be shareable in public?

Answer (score 0):

You have added extra slash in the beginning and middle of your code.

Instead of:

```
By.xpath("(//input[@id='address'])[1]")).sendKeys("banglore");
```

it should be:

```
By.xpath("//input[@id='address'][1]")).sendKeys("banglore");
```

If that also does not work, kindly share your html url. Will check again.

Comment: I still don't find `By.xpath("(//input..` in OP's code trials.